# Inno: Write User and Serial to Registry

Tags: inno-setup

During my inno installation I'm trying to write the username and serial to the registry and I get the following error during compile:

```
Invalid prototype for 'RegisteredUser'
```

Chunk from Inno

```
[Code]
function RegisteredUser(): String;
begin
  Result := 'test';
end;

[Registry] 
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Platform\Brand"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "RegisteredUser"; ValueData: {code:RegisteredUser};
```

Any ideas?

Or if I can create the registry directly in [Code] that would work also
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently in inno-setup the function called by `{code:block}` must be a single string parameter function (even if you do not use it.

```
function RegisteredUser(Param: String): string;
begin
  Result := SerialPage.Values[0];
end;
```

Comment: Yes, functions called from non-[Code] areas must have a single string parameter.  This gives them a lot of flexibility to do things like:  
  
`[Files]  
Source: "B\MYFILE.TXT"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: DirExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\SubDir'))`  
  
Check out the "Check parameters" entry in the Inno Setup Help Index for a full discussion.